# Name of the operation where whole table is put in array format

Tags: naming

Consider this data struture:

```
key1 : value1
key2 : value2
key3 : value3
```

I have an operation that put this data in array format:

```
key1, value1, key2, value2, key3, value3
```

Which would the the name of this operation?

As far as I know, "collate" would be the opposite process, and "[vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics))" would be about putting the data in a single column, not a single row.

Comment: "convert dictionary to list"

Comment: The term "transpose" means you change the direction of an array. Perhaps this is what you are looking for

Comment: @JohnKouraklis, "pivot" is similar